# snowflake regular expression extract data

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use snowflake regexp_replace to extract data out of a string

This is my string

I just want the date value, in this case it should be `20210101`.

I know how to extract this from normal regular expression with `(?<=DATE_ID=)(.*)(?=/)`, but apparently,  snowflake does not recognize question mark:

```
Status: ERROR
(SQLSTATE: 2201B, SQLCODE: 100048): Invalid regular expression: '(?<=DATE_ID=)(.*)(?=/)', no argument for repetition operator: ?
```

Does anyone know how to do this in snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern with a capturing group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'DATE_ID=([^/]*)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, 'DATE_ID=([^/]*)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxNnVw/1).

*Details*:

- `DATE_ID=` - the text that is matched and consumed
- `([^/]*)` - any zero or more chars other than a `/` char that is captured into Group 1.

The first two `1` arguments after the pattern are position and occurrence arguments, `e` tells the engine to return the contents of the first capturing group. So, you may keep the last `1` argument (group number), or you may omit it.

See more about [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_substr.html#regexp-substr) in the documentation.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, you just saved my day. Thank you very much!